# "Error: Permission denied" while trying to edit txt file C++

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and currently I"m getting a really weird error, telling me that permission is denied I've tried changing the permissions of it in the properties. I've tried disabling my antivirus, and I've even restarted my PC. Nothing I've done seems to be working to fix it. Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream file("testfile1.txt");

    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
    }

    file << "Hello";

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: have you tried with another file?

Comment: @VictorJimenez99 yes

Comment: Several questions. Have you tried used the full path to the file? How are you running the program? What OS? Can you show an example running the program on the command line and a directory listing.

Comment: @pcarter I'm using Windows 10, I'm using VS Code, and I have tried running it out of the integrated terminal as far as running it in administrator cmd prompt. I also have tried using the full directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/104404/3/) source, they claim to have a similar problem also using window 10. All replies here point to a security feature not letting .exe programs to write to files. This is obviously a malware protection thing. The sure solution is to find a way to disable this. But your case seems to be a little different than this person's.

I recommend since you are doing everything through your IDE to try and change the path that it gets saved in.

Comment: I'm using avast if that helps at all, the free version specifically. But then again I've disabled it and still had the issue.

Comment: SHOOT there was another setting I didn't disable ransomware shield, that was it! Thanks for  the advice man!

Answer (score 0):

are the permissions to access the file for USER set to allow?
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZJeJ.png)

Comment: They are, and it still hasn't changed. I tried it on a C++ compiler website, and I got no issues there.

Comment: under Properties -> General  check if Attributes is set to read-only, if it is then uncheck it